# Cast current day to english

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I got this query

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'DAY') from dual
```

This returns the day of the week in letters. The language depends on whatever the user is using. But I want it always to display in English. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the third optional parameter in [TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129) function.
It should be something like this, 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = language'.

```
select to_char(SYSDATE,'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') eng,
       to_char(SYSDATE,'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=GERMAN') ger,
       to_char(SYSDATE,'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=FRENCH') fre,
       to_char(SYSDATE,'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ITALIAN') itl
from dual;


|       ENG |        GER |      FRE |       ITL |
|-----------|------------|----------|-----------|
| Thursday  | Donnerstag | Jeudi    | Giovedì   |
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
    SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'DAY') from dual set language English
```

append to last in your query. Read

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/390429/SQL-Server-Date-Format-Language

more info.

Comment: This is not valid in either Oracle or SQL Server.